serverless framework: Internal Serverless Error
Prior to upgrading to serverless v4.0.30, I was getting "functionHandler is not defined" errors as in https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12542. The workaround suggested in that issue was I believe to set frameworkVersion lower, but that didn't work for me (see this question).
Luckily they fixed the issue in the next version in theory, so I upgraded. Now however I get the following error:
✖ Internal Serverless Error
Error: Internal Serverless Error
    at UsersClient.makeRequest (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:146:342373)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async UsersClient._get (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:146:341459)
    at async refreshUserIdTokenAndSave (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:178:2596)
    at async getAuthenticatedData (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:177:4996)
    at async commandSupport (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:798:1303)
    at async Object.handler (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1068:6748)

upon running pretty much any severless command (start, deploy, init). Anyone else gotten or managed to resolve this issue? Perhaps also related, can I clear any local cache or otherwise reset my state to try & resolve this?

This issue is being tracked here in Github: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12583

there still error with 4.1.2 version, after downgrade to 3.39.0 error is gone.

How do you downgrade?

I ran the following & now I'm properly on a lower version & things seems to be working again:
rm -r .serverless #in my directory
npm uninstall -g serverless
npm install -g serverless@3.39.0
serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline
